# Jupyter Hub on Dask using Internal LoadBalancer

Tags: dask, dask-kubernetes

I wanted to ask you if anyone has experience with configuring Jupyterhub on DASK with Internal Load balancer? Default setup comes with External 
Preferably if Jupyter Hub's Load balancer would be mapped to a specific Internal IP or subnet?
I'm trying to setup and environment which would not be accessible from outside.

I have managed to setup JupytherHub with Internal LoadBalancer previously by editing the config.yaml using this this repo for installation: https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/

```
proxy: 
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
      annotations: {service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "internal subnet"}
```

but this is not possible with dask.

Is there a way to achieve this or some another way?
Any suggestions welcome!

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on how you are setting up dask? Are you using dask kubernetes of the dask helm chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

I was able to do so with the following kubectl command:

`kubectl annotate svc dask-scheduler cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type=Internal`

After about 30 seconds the IP address will transfer to an internal one, if you have provisioned enough IP addresses for the sevices to utilise (you many need to allow more).